# Include em endereço absoluto

Tags: php, include

Estou tentando incluir o arquivo config.php que está na pasta raiz do site. Porém, tambem tenho o arquivo header.php na raiz do site e todos as páginas estão em uma pasta com este nome, então o arquivo fica o seguinte.

```
<?php
include('../config.php');
include('../header.php'); ?>
conteudo...
</?php include('../footer.php);
```

> Para link absoluto já tentei:

`include("http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/config.php");`

> Erro apresentado no servidor online:

Também não obtive sucesso.
    Warning
    : include(../config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
    /home/u655246247/public_html/paginas/artigos.php
    on line
    2

> Linha 2: é exatamente aonde quero chegar ->
>   **include('../config.php');**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provavelmente é isto que você procura:

```
include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config.php' );
```

Assim você tem o caminho absoluto de include em relação ao disco, e não ao URL do site.

Se tiver curiosidade de entender, use esta linha num script de teste:

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

O resultado será algo como `/var/www/httpdocs` em Linux, ou algo do tipo `c:\apache\httpdocs` no Windows.

**Notas:**

- certifique-se de o nome do arquivo estar correto. `Config.php` e `config.php` não são o mesmo arquivo em Linux.
- certifique-se também de os arquivos envolvidos terem permissão de leitura para o servidor de páginas.
- obviamente, o arquivo tem que estar na mesma pasta que o caminho indicado :)

Comment: No localhost continua funcionando perfeitamente. Porém, os erros persistem online, exatamente os mesmos. Eu dei um echo no arquivo config.php pra testar, e o echo foi incluido, mas a variavel conexão não é encontrada. O erro: 
Warning
: include(/home/u655246247/public_html/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
/home/u655246247/public_html/paginas/textos.php
on line
2

Comment: Irei adicionar o arquivo config.php na pergunta para observações..

Comment: @ThiagoBarros nao adianta adicionar, ele nao está sendo lido. Melhor incluir uma listagem do diretório `public_html`, para vermos as permissões e os nomes.

Comment: Sim, mas quando dou um echo, o texto é exibido na página... por que?

Comment: Quando dá um echo onde? Inclua uma listagem do diretório public_html para vermos as permissões.

Comment: Não queira me matar, mas o arquivo estava com outro nome no servidor online.. rsrs
Após consertar, o servidor online me exibiu outro erro: Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in /home/u655246247/public_html/paginas/textos.php on line 54

Comment: @ThiagoBarros ai é por você estar usando o http:// em vez do caminho absoluto. E nao, nao quero matar ninguem, veja o item 3 que eu já tinha adicionado na resposta :) Lembre-se que quando dá include, o caminho absoluto é o do HD, e não da web. O `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` te dá a raiz do seu site, mas no caminho do HD.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34735/discussion-between-thiago-barros-and-bacco).